# If e Else em Comandos Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Como faço para verificar se um comando foi digitado corretamente ou não? Por exemplo, se o usuário digitar um comando que não existe, irá exibir uma mensagem de advertência, caso contrário, irá executar o comando. Eu construí o código parcialmente e tentei com `if` e `else` mas não sei onde estou errando, lembrando que estou inciando em Python:

Código:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['ajuda'])
def command_help(m):
    cid = m.chat.id
    help_text = "Comandos disponíveis: \n"
        for key in commands:
            help_text += "/" + key + ": "
            help_text += commands[key] + "\n"
        bot.send_message(cid, help_text)

# AQUI QUE QUERO FAZER A CONDIÇÃO if e else:
@bot.message_handler(commands=['exec'])
def command_exec(m):
    cid = m.chat.id
    if m.text is not None:  # PROBLEMAS AQUI!!
        bot.send_message(cid, "Ejecutando: " + m.text[len("/exec"):])
        bot.send_chat_action(cid, 'typing')
        time.sleep(2)
        f = os.popen(m.text[len("/exec"):])
        result = f.read()
        bot.send_message(cid, "Resultado: " + result)
    else: # E PROBLEMAS AQUI TAMBÉM!!
        bot.send_message(cid, " COMANDO INVÁLIDO!!")
        print(color.RED + " COMANDO INVÁLIDO!! " + color.ENDC)

@bot.message_handler()
def info_opt(m):
        cid = m.chat.id
        txt = m.text
        if txt == "TEMP":  # TEMP
            bot.send_message(cid, "[+] TEMPERATURAS")
            print(color.BLUE + "[+] TEMPERATURAS" + color.ENDC)
            # cpu temp
            tempFile = open( "/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp" )
            cpu_temp = tempFile.read()
            tempFile.close()
            cpu_temp = round(float(cpu_temp)/1000)
            bot.send_message(cid, "  [i]   CPU: %s" % cpu_temp)
            print(color.GREEN + " [i] CPU: %s" % cpu_temp + color.ENDC)
            # gpu temp
            gpu_temp = os.popen('/opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd measure_temp').read().split("=")[1][:-3]
            bot.send_message(cid, "  [i]   GPU: %s" % gpu_temp)
            print(color.GREEN + " [i] GPU: %s" % gpu_temp + color.ENDC)

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Se puderem me retornar esse código corrigido eu agradeço muito.

Comment: Não ficou claro qual é exatamente o problema com as estruturas `if/else`

Comment: Por exemplo, o código acima, quando o usuário digitar o comando: /exec temp, irá retornar uma informação, mas eu queria que quando o usuário digitar: /exec asdf, exiba uma mensagem de advertência que o comando não existe. No código eu coloquei as condições IF e ESLE, mas não funciona.